# How to add more promises based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have a few API calls which I only need to make when my code is executed in edit mode, but I have one certain API call which has to be made in create and edit, both modes.

Here is the code which I've written as of now:

```js
// other controller code
var config = {};

var image = {
  dc: { name: 'abc' },
  cl: { name: 'def' },
  ds: { name: 'ghi' },
  net: { name: 'jkl' }
};

// Turns on the loader
vm.loading = true;

// I'll always have to get list of DCs, be it create or edit mode
promise = getDc()
  .then(function(response) {
    config.dc = response.data.dc;
    return $q.resolve(response.data.dc);
  }, function() {
    return $q.reject('Failed to get DCs');
  })

// If edit mode, I need to fetch list of Cls, Nets and DSs.
// These all are dependent on list of DCs.
if (editMode) {
  promise
    .then(function(dcs) {
      image.dc = _.find(dcs, { name: image.dc.name });

      return $q.all([
          getCl(image.dc),
          getNet(image.dc)
        ])
        .then(function(response) {
          config.cl = response[0].data.cls;
          config.net = response[1].data.nets;

          return $q.resolve([response[0].data.cls, response[1].data.nets]);
        }, function() {
          return $q.reject('Failed to get cls or nets');
        });
    })
    .then(function(lists) {
      image.cl = _.find(lists[0], { name: image.cl.name });
      image.net = _.find(lists[1], { name: image.net.name });

      return getDs(image.dc, image.cl)
        .then(function(response) {
          config.ds = response.data.ds;

          return $q.resolve(response.data.ds);
        }, function() {
          return $q.reject('Failed to get DSs');
        });
    })
    .then(function(dss) {
      image.ds = _.find(dss, { name: image.ds.name });
      return $q.resolve();
    });
}

promise
  .then(function() {
    // Will open modal here
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Print any error thrown in between
    console.error(error);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    // Turns off the loader
    vm.loading = false;
  });
```

So, in the create mode, I will directly open the modal after fetching the DCs, but in edit mode, I will have to load several other things as well.

The problem here is that the loader shows only until the DCs are loaded, and modal is opened just after that. It doesn't wait for other elements to be loaded first.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise chain you created after `if (editMode) {` is derived from your original promise but it doesn't replace it. That whole chain is executed independently of the logic you've defined after the if() condition. To fix the issue, reassign the promise:

```
if (editMode) {
  promise = promise
    .then(function(dcs) {
    ...
}
```